# Debugging SMTP email failures - GSuite

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, google-workspace

I am working on an eCommerce site that sends a number of emails to the customer when they complete their order using G Suite SMTP relay service. But a large number of these emails are failing. There does not seems to be any pattern to it either - sometimes all emails will send, some times just one or two, and sometimes none.

I am getting the following error: `421, "4.7.0", Try again later, closing connection`.

Looking here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en doesn't really help me debug this or figure out why some emails fail.

I am using the phpmailer class (https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

The issue seems to occur when the first handshake fails:

```
function Hello($host="") {
    $this->error = null; # so no confusion is caused

    if(!$this->connected()) {
      $this->error = array(
            "error" => "Called Hello() without being connected");
      return false;
    }

    # if a hostname for the HELO was not specified determine
    # a suitable one to send
    if(empty($host)) {
      # we need to determine some sort of appopiate default
      # to send to the server
      $host = "localhost";
    }

    // Send extended hello first (RFC 2821)
    //If this fails then the second attempt will always fail
    if(!$this->SendHello("EHLO", $host))
    {
      //when this fails it generates the try again later error
      if(!$this->SendHello("HELO", $host))
          return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

So what is the best approach for debugging this?

Comment: Add debug logger and Step logging to identify the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty explicit. You call a 3rd party web service, which returns an error code which says the server you are calling is at capacity, try later. Is this a free service which allows you to upgrade to a paid plan? Usually whee you see his kind of thing.

Comment: Yes it is Google G Suite SMTP relay service we use, which is paid for. There is a max limit of 10k emails we can send a day and we are no where near that, I find it hard to imagine one of Google's servers being at capacity.